# pam_cracklib not enforcing difok for root even with enforce_for_root option

Tags: linux, debian, pam

I tried enforcing difok=7 for root but can't get it to work. By now I tried every combination and it's just not working. I can't find any information in the manpage about this problem.

Is this normal that pam_cracklib is not enforcing difok=7 for root?

This is the configuration I am using: `password        requisite                       pam_pwquality.so retry=3 difok=7 minlen=10 ucredit=-1 dcredit=-1 maxrepeat=3 reject_username enforce_for_root`

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239002/why-roots-password-change-doesnt-require-old-password.
In short: When you change the password for root it does not check for the old password, because this check would be pointless as it adds no additional security.

Comment: The answer does not actually answer the question.